# What are the allowed $W$ bosons in Muon decay?

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, elementary-particles, weak-interaction, electroweak

I am curious about the allowed Feynman diagrams in Muon decay and whether the $W$ boson can be either the $W^+$ or $W^-$. Muon decay follows the reaction:
\begin{equation}
\mu^-\rightarrow e^-+\overline{\nu}_{e}+\nu_\mu
\end{equation}

I am sure the W$^-$ diagram is valid: [image]

But I am not sure if the W$^+$ diagram is allowed since here the W$^+$, $\bar{\nu}_e$, $\nu_\mu$ are created out of the vacuum. And created kind of before the muon decays.
[image]

My question is whether both Feynman diagrams are valid for muon decay or if only the W$^-$ is allowed?

Comment: You are misreading Feynman diagrams, by taking the x-axis to represent time. If the second diagram were thought to bring momentum and energy Into the muon vertex, it is the *same* diagram as the first. A W+ into the vertex is the same as a W- out of the vertex.

Comment: Thanks Cosmas, this is the correct answer. This forum asked the same question: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/muon-decay-feynman-graph.589383/

Comment: If you thought of charge conservation at each vertex, you would see that the arrow of time for the W should be into the vertex, making it a W-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These diagrams represent the same process. A $W^+$ going into a vertex is equivalent to a $W^-$ going out of a vertex